# IF Statement multiple conditions, same statement

Tags: c#

Hey all, looking to reduce the code on my c# if statements as there are several repeating factors and was wondering if a trimmer solution is possible.

I currently have 2 if statements that need to carry out an identical statement, however the only variable is an extra condition on an if statement when a checkbox is not checked. Im just wondering if there is a way to make it one statement or make the condition string variable, heres the compressed version of the code:

```
if (checkbox.checked)
  {
    if (columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
  }
else
  {
    if (columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c 
        && columnname != A2)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
  }
```

Its like I need to run an if statement within the conditions of an if statement if that makes sense, like this psuedo form:

```
if (columnname != a 
    && columnname != b 
    && columnname != c 
    && if(checkbox.checked{columnname != A2})
```

Comment: BTW - the same answer works in C, C++ and Java.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the `&&` (and) operator in combination with the `||` (or) operator in a nested condition as so:

```
if (columnname != a 
  && columnname != b 
  && columnname != c
  && (checkbox.checked || columnname != A2))
{
   "statement 1"
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: usually when my conditions in an if statements are more than three, I extract them to a private method just to make it clear what's the condition is

Comment: @PrashantCholachagudda I don't see how static values being abstracted to somewhere else helps discern 'what they are' in any way. Do you have an example or an article on what that looks like and what the benefit is?

Comment: @TylerH When multiple devs code together, each dev would have to spend time understanding the multiple conditions. A single well named method or function helps devs understand what these conditions do. I agree with Prashant here and 3 is a good number when one must consider creating a private method containing these if conditions. The reference article below can be helpful to understand this. 
Ref: https://medium.com/readable-code/readable-code-how-to-write-readable-conditional-statements-626cb17a1d2a

Comment: @Shankar Your explanation doesn't make sense. Multiple devs would still have to "spend time understanding" the conditions in a private method, no different from this situation. But worse, now it's in another method, and not here. Seems like _more_ work to me, not less.

Answer (score 12):

```
if (columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c 
        && (columnname != A2 || checkbox.checked))
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

I always try to factor out complex boolean expressions into meaningful variables (you could probably think of better names based on what these columns are used for):

```
bool notColumnsABC = (columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c);
bool notColumnA2OrBoxIsChecked = ( columnname != A2 || checkbox.checked );

if (   notColumnsABC 
    && notColumnA2OrBoxIsChecked )
  {
      "statement 1"
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Check this for a more clustered way of checking conditions:

```
private bool IsColumn(string col, params string[] names) => names.Any(n => n == col);
```

usage:

```
private void CheckColumn()
{
     if(!IsColumn(ColName, "Column A", "Column B", "Column C"))
    {
     //not A B C column
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this the same:

```
if ((checkbox.checked || columnname != A2) && 
        columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c)
  {
      "statement 1"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this if you think it's more clear:

```
if (columnname != a 
  && columnname != b 
  && columnname != c
{
   if (checkbox.checked || columnname != A2)
   {
      "statement 1"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about maybe something like this?

```
    var condCheck1 = new string[]{"a","b","c"};
    var condCheck2 = new string[]{"a","b","c","A2"}

    if(!condCheck1.Contains(columnName) && !checkbox.checked)
        //statement 1
    else if (!condCheck2.Contains(columnName))
        //statment 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @sal said, C# 9.0 [added improved pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements). You can now use `is` with `and` and `or.`

With this, the code:

```
if (checkbox.checked)
  {
    if (columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
  }
else
  {
    if (columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c 
        && columnname != A2)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
  }
```

Can be reduced to:

```
if (checkbox.checked)
  {
    if (columnname is (!= a and != b and != c)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
  }
else
  {
    if (columnname is (!= a and != b and != c and != A2)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
  }
```

This pattern matching also added cleaning up switch statements in a similar way. Definitely worth using.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late but worth the information

C#9 : you can write

```
if (columnname is not a or b or c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkbox.checked && columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
else if (columnname != a && columnname != b && columnname != c 
        && columnname != A2)
    {
      "statement 1"
    }
```

is one way to simplify a little.

Answer (score 0):

I think agileguy has the correct answer, but I would like to add that for more difficult situations there are a couple of strategies I take to solve the problem.  The first is to use a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).  If you Google "truth table" you will run across some examples related directly to programming and computer science.

Another strategy I take is to use an anonymous function to encapsulate common logic between various conditions.  Create it right before the if block, then use it where needed.  This seems to create code that is more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

```
var test = new char[] {a, b, c}.Contains(columnname));

if(test)
{
  "true statement"
}
else
{
   "false statement"
}
```

Comment: This repeats, in essence, Sturm's answer from 2 years prior.