# Shortening Multiple IF Conditions for the Same Variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement

(first stackoverflow post)
This is a javaScript question, but I think the logic applies anywhere

I've wondered for a long time about using an if statement to compare multiple values against the same variable without needing to type out the variable every time; specifically, in regards to "greater than" and "less than".

The specific example I'm trying to solve is:

```
var middle = 5;
if(middle < 10 && middle > 0) {
    //some stuff
}
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
var middle = 5;
if(middle (< 10 && > 0)) {
    //the same stuff
}
```

I have checked [is-there-a-way-to-shorten-the-condition-if-it-always-compares-to-the-same-thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637988/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-the-condition-if-it-always-compares-to-the-same-thing)
and [if-statements-matching-multiple-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907299/if-statements-matching-multiple-values)
and [if-statement-multiple-conditions-same-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341513/if-statement-multiple-conditions-same-statement).
I could not derive a simple answer to my specific question from those.

A final note: I do not want to make a new "multiple if" function that accepts arguments and then compares them for the variable. I am looking for a "built-in" way to do this.

Thanks,
-Charles

Comment: how many range binding comparisons do you actually need? Usually only two are necessary.

Comment: There is no such way. You can write a wrapper function that returns a boolean value, but you'll still have to write the logic out in that.

Comment: Huh... After some (failed) attempts, I've determined that it's not as easy as I thought to make the wrapper function without using eval().
Any tips on this side question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some languages like [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) and [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#comparisons) (which compiles to JS!) have *chained comparisons*:

```
if (0 < middle < 10)
```

However, **Javascript does not** have these. Just as you already do, you will need to reference the variable twice:

```
if (0 < middle && middle < 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. That was the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible, for a logical operator you need both sides of the operator to evaluate to true or false.

If you are missing a side the statement can't be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a "built-in" way to do this.

Javascript doesn' t support this feature. In fact, most languages don't and Python is the only famous example I can think of right now that does that (you can write `0 < middle < 10`  there).

In Javascript, the best you can do is use a shorter variable name

```
if(0 <= x && x < 10)
```

Or abstract common tests into a function

```
if(between(0, x, 10))
```

Comment: That's 4 more characters, not even counting white space! :D

Comment: It's only four more characters because 'x' is very short. If your variable were 10 characters, then it would start to be clearly shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Right, don't do this, but just for the sake of it :

```
if (Math.min(10, Math.max(0, middle)) == middle) {
   // middle is between 0 and 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is doing this in python for multiple values you can try this

```
exclude = ['10','0','20','30','12','14']
if i not in exclude:
   print(i)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).